# Port scan in python

Tags: python

I am a new Python learner. Can anyone help me with a basic script to scan http and https ports and return the ip addresses after the user inputs subnet such as 192.168.1.0/24 ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Python_Learner! Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but you have to try before and post more details. Please see “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A while back, I wrote a TCP port scanner in Python. It works nicely and is easily configurable. You type in an IP or internet address, and it outputs the ports you scanned. It is in 50 lines of Python 2.7. Have fun!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PIES v1.1
# SYZYGY-DEV333
# Simple TCP port scanner in Python
# Apache Version 2

from socket import *
import sys, time
from datetime import datetime

host = ''
max_port = 5000
min_port = 1

def scan_host(host, port, r_code = 1):
    try:
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        code = s.connect_ex((host, port))
        if code == 0:
            r_code = code
        s.close()
    except Exception, e:
        pass
    return r_code

try:
    host = raw_input(">> Enter Target Host Address: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n\n>> User Requested An Interrupt.")
    print(">> Application Shutting Down.")
    sys.exit(1)

hostip = gethostbyname(host)
print("\n>> Host: %s IP: %s" % (host, hostip))
print(">> Scanning Started At %s...\n" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
start_time = datetime.now()

for port in range(min_port, max_port):
    try:
        response = scan_host(host, port)
        if response == 0:
            print(">> Port %d: Open" % (port))
    except Exception, e:
        pass

stop_time = datetime.now()
total_time_duration = stop_time - start_time
print("\n>> Scanning Finsihed At %s ..." % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
print(">> Scanning Duration: %s ..." % (total_time_duration))
print(">> Have a nice day!")
```

See my project here: https://github.com/SYZYGY-DEV333/PIES